# What is pub tool?

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub

I was studying basics of Flutter and Dart development and came across package manager called **pub**. What is it and what is it's importance in Flutter development?

Comment: Why negative vote?

Answer (score 3):

Pub is the package manager for the Dart programming language, containing reusable libraries & packages for Flutter, AngularDart, and general Dart programs.

Some basic command:

- Use `pub get` to get dependencies
- Use `pub upgrade` to upgrade a dependency
- Use `pub publish` to make your library available for others

You can find all packages [here](https://pub.dartlang.org).

Also you can develop your own package, find the [details](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages) on official site.

Answer (score 0):

Pub is a package manager for dart to know more about pub see this: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub